# Flutter Mysql using PHP api

Tags: php, json, flutter, dart, mysqli

I have a problem with this error for a long time and I really don't know how to solve it. I saw from various sources that there should be a problem with JSON decoding, but I have done it according to the instructions several times and the problem did not arise there. The error is as follows:

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www....
^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1250:9)
#2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:915:22)
#3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10)
#4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
#5      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:216:41)
#6      _RegisterState.register (package:projectbicycle/example/register.dart:25:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

register.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:projectbicycle/dashboard.dart';
import 'package:projectbicycle/main.dart';

class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  const Register({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RegisterState createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {
  TextEditingController user = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController pass = TextEditingController();

  Future register() async {
    var url = Uri.http("95.105.178.9", '/api_bike/register.php', {'q': '{http}'});
    var response = await http.post(url, body: {
      "username": user.text.toString(),
      "password": pass.text.toString()
    });
    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    if (data == "Error") {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        msg: 'User already exit!',
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      );
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        msg: 'Registration Successful',
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      );
      Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => DashBoard(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
  bool isPasswordVisible = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          width: double.infinity,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Colors.teal.shade200, Colors.purple.shade900])),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 300,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        gradient:
                        LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.red, Colors.yellow]),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              blurRadius: 4,
                              spreadRadius: 3,
                              color: Colors.black12)
                        ],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(200),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(200))),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 35, left: 65),
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          const Text(
                            'Let\'s',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 30,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                shadows: [
                                  Shadow(
                                      color: Colors.black45,
                                      offset: Offset(1, 1),
                                      blurRadius: 5)
                                ]),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            ' Register',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 30,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.pink.shade600,
                                shadows: const [
                                  Shadow(
                                      color: Colors.black45,
                                      offset: Offset(1, 1),
                                      blurRadius: 5)
                                ]),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 40,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30)
                      .copyWith(bottom: 10),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: user,
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14.5),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIconConstraints:
                        const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 45),
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(
                          Icons.alternate_email_outlined,
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          size: 22,
                        ),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'Enter Username',
                        hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white60, fontSize: 14.5),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100).copyWith(
                                bottomRight: const Radius.circular(0)),
                            borderSide:
                            const BorderSide(color: Colors.white38)),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100).copyWith(
                                bottomRight: const Radius.circular(0)),
                            borderSide:
                            const BorderSide(color: Colors.white70))),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30)
                      .copyWith(bottom: 10),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: pass,
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14.5),
                    obscureText: isPasswordVisible ? false : true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIconConstraints:
                        const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 45),
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(
                          Icons.lock,
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          size: 22,
                        ),
                        suffixIconConstraints:
                        const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 45, maxWidth: 46),
                        suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              isPasswordVisible = !isPasswordVisible;
                            });
                          },
                          child: Icon(
                            isPasswordVisible
                                ? Icons.visibility
                                : Icons.visibility_off,
                            color: Colors.white70,
                            size: 22,
                          ),
                        ),
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'Enter Password',
                        hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white60, fontSize: 14.5),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100).copyWith(
                                bottomRight: const Radius.circular(0)),
                            borderSide:
                            const BorderSide(color: Colors.white38)),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100).copyWith(
                                bottomRight: const Radius.circular(0)),
                            borderSide:
                            const BorderSide(color: Colors.white70))),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    register();
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 53,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              blurRadius: 4,
                              color: Colors.black12.withOpacity(.2),
                              offset: const Offset(2, 2))
                        ],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)
                            .copyWith(bottomRight: const Radius.circular(0)),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                          Colors.purple.shade600,
                          Colors.amber.shade900
                        ])),
                    child: Text('Signup',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.8),
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                const Text('Already have an account?',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 13)),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MyHomePage()),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 53,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white60),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)
                          .copyWith(bottomRight: const Radius.circular(0)),
                    ),
                    child: Text('Login',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.8),
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

register.php

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','userdata');
if(!$db)
{
    echo "Database connection failed";
}
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count == 1){
    echo json_encode("Error");
}else{
    $insert = "INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."')";
        $query = mysqli_query($db,$insert);
        if($query){
            echo json_encode("Success");
        }
}
?>
```

I will be very grateful for any help, as I said, I know that there should obviously be a problem in decoding, but I really don't know where and how to fix it

I've tried different variations of decoding and several direct instructions, the one mentioned is a YouTube tutorial where it works. and it doesn't show any error.

Comment: Well clearly, from the error message, your PHP script is not returning JSON, it's returning HTML (since what it's pointing to as invalid JSON is evidently the start of a HTML document). Probably this is because the PHP code crashed and threw an error, which it then tried to display in a HTML document. And of course HTML isn't JSON so you can't decode it with JSON-decoding functions. Better read the whole HTML response to see what the error was, and/or configure PHP to log errors to a log file on the server instead.

Comment: P.S. **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use it again.

Comment: Also, please don't store passwords in plain text - that is another security risk. Learn about [password hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead. See also [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords)

Comment: Never configure your web app to login to the database as `root`. Root can do whatever it likes, so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities this just leaves your database an open book for hackers. Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly. Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: @ADyson your answer is good, why put in the comment?

Comment: @SayyidJ because none of my comments are answers - they don't resolve the problem. They merely point the OP in the right direction for how to find out what the underlying problem actually is. I can't tell them what to change in their code in order to resolve this because I don't know what error the PHP is throwing. I can merely tell them why the JSON decoding is failing. And my other comments are asides about the quality of their code rather than solutions to the specific quesiton.

Comment: @ADyson hello, thank you for the answer, especially regarding SQL protection, I will use it in other projects, I usually hash the password using MD5 and do not give it as text, this is directly from the instructions that worked, that's why I showed it here, the PHP script works directly, it doesn't show any errors, writes to the database (without name and password, of course) when I connect to it using the browser URL.

Comment: It also has a status of 200 and the header is json, so I don't understand. I read somewhere that it only shows in the emulator, but it just seems like crap when everything works on the given video.

Comment: `I usually hash the password`...md5 is [obsolete and insecure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) for the purposes of password hashing, so don't use that either.

Comment: `It also has a status of 200 and the header is json`...well ok, but clearly something is wrong within the content, regardless of those other indicators. So did you look at the complete raw response received by your dart code? You should be able to log `response.body` before you try to decode it as JSON, and see what's really in there.

Comment: You could also test sending a POST request (with the parameters filled in) to the PHP using a tool such as Postman and see if you can make that work. That might help you to see if the problem is primarily on the PHP side, or the dart side.

Comment: hello guys thanks for help, i solved the problem. I have bad ip in host so the way was wrong. Really stupid mistake. sorry, but thaks for that help with secure database i will used it ther and in other projects :)